# Get the file from a folder by file number in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file

I want to get the specific file from the folder depending on its number.
For example I want the 3rd file from the folder ASP in c: drive or
I want 10th file from the same folder then how can I get that using VB.NET?

I have tried the following code but I don't know for the specific file.

```
Dim Files() As String
Files = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\VB")
```

Comment: I can get all the files by GetFile method but I don't know how to get the specific file

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!st get all the files from the Directory & store it in an Array. After that use FileInfo class to get the specific file by just passing the desired file number.

```
Dim arr As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\VB")
Dim file As New FileInfo(arr(5))
```